# PHP:magic_quotes_gpc can not start

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I set the "magic_quotes_gpc" with the value "on" in php.ini,just like the following:

```
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/magic-quotes-gpc
magic_quotes_gpc = On
```

but it seems doesn't work and I test this with the following php code:

```
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    echo "hello world<br />";
}
```

it will always print "hello world",whether it is "on" or "off".
addition,I use wampserver 2.4 in my computer！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WampServer 2.4 comes with PHP 5.4, and as the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) say, get_magic_quotes_gpc() always returns false since PHP 5.4.0, for the (horrible) feature was removed from the language. You can't have magic_quotes.

Comment: tank you very much!sorry for my carelessness!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check your PHP version:

> Magic Quotes has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

If you want to implement `magic_quotes_gpc` on PHP 5.4 above version, you could use [yidas/magic-quotes](https://github.com/yidas/php-magic-quotes) which works the same as `magic_quotes_gpc`.

> https://github.com/yidas/php-magic-quotes